# Selecting NSCollectionView Item

Tags: macos, nscollectionview

I need to create a photo gallery and each individual photo when selected will have some options to edit. For this am using NSCollectionView to set up the grid layout. I followed [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CollectionViews/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009030) guide and the basic grid layout is setup.

Now I need to enable selection of these images. So that when I click on them it gets a check mark, and later I need to enable batch processing of these images(copy/delete ...).

I am stuck here, and couldnt get any info on how to handle selection and later get the selected items from the grid ?